# Proving some trigonometric series are convergent

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I have to prove that if $(a_k)_k$ is decreasing and tending to 0, then, for all $\epsilon>0$, the series $\sum a_k \sin(2\pi kx), \sum a_k \cos(2\pi kx)$ and $\sum a_k e^{2\pi ikx}$ are all uniformly convergent on $(\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$. I have to use the fact that if $(v_k)_k$ is positive and decrasing and $(u_k)_k$ an arbitrary sucession, then
$$
|u_1v_1+...+u_nv_n| \leq v_1\max_n \left|\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\right|
$$
I have seen a proof using that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(2\pi kx)=\csc(\pi x)\sin(N\pi x)\sin((N+1)\pi x)$$
but I would like to know how to prove that equality because I can't see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? It's important to show us what you have tried, or at least provide us context of where the problem came from and what you know about it.

Comment: Also, are you sure your second inequality is right? You have $n$ as a free variable on the left side, but $n$ is a bound variable (under the max) on the right.

Comment: The first inequality comes from another exercise before this one, it was an indication to use it in this exercise, I don't know how to prove it but is with summation by parts in theory. I tried applying this inequality to $a_1$ and trying to show that the max of the sumatory is finite, so I can take limits and show the absolute convergence of the series, but I don't know how to prove that convergence. Thanks for the comment